# How to calculate average of each column in a HTML table using the <script> tag or using aggregate()

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I have this .ejs page which contains a table. In that table, there are 4 columns which contain numbers. I want to display an average of each of these columns on the same page.

I have managed to get the averages, but it is very inefficient and is taking up a lot of space in the .ejs file.

This is what the page looks like.

[image: 1]

Here is my code for the .ejs file (including my poorly coded average "calculator"):

> 

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<html>

<head>

    <title>MTU Phone Usage Monitor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/styleTable.css"></link>
</head>


<body>
    <div class="banner">
        <div class="navbar">
            <img src="\images\logo.png" class="logo">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/phone/create">New Entry</a></li>
                <li><a href="/table">View Data</a></li>
                <li><a href="/help">Help</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <form action="/phone/find" method="post"></form>
        <div class="table-wrapper">
            <table class="tableData" id="table">
                <caption>
                    <%= title %>
                </caption>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Education Usage</th>
                        <th>Shopping Usage</th>
                        <th>Searching/Browsing usage</th>
                        <th>Social Media usage</th>
                        <th>Date and Time</th>
                        <th></th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <% for(var i=0; i < phonelist.length; i++) { %>
                        <tr>

                            <td>
                                <%= phonelist[i].name %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%= phonelist[i].timeEducation %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%= phonelist[i].timeShopping %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%= phonelist[i].timeBrowsing %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%= phonelist[i].timeSocial %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%= phonelist[i].createdAt %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="secret">
                                    <form action="/phone/delete" method="post"> <input type="String" value="<%= phonelist[i].id%>" name="id" readonly><button type="Submit">Delete</button></form>
                                    <form action="/phone/update" method="post"> <input type="String" value="<%=phonelist[i].id%>" name="id" readonly><button type="Submit">Update</button></form>
                                </div>
                            </td>


                        </tr>
                        <% } %>

        </div>
        <span id="education"></span><br>
        <span id="shopping"></span><br>
        <span id="browsing"></span><br>
        <span id="social"></span>
        <script>
            var table = document.getElementById("table"),
                avgVal, sumVal = 0,
                rowCount = table.rows.length - 1; // minus the header

            //calculate average education usage
            for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
                sumVal = sumVal + parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML);
            }

            document.getElementById("education").innerHTML = "Average Education = " + parseFloat(sumVal / rowCount);
            avgVal, sumVal = 0;

            //calculate average shopping usage
            for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
                sumVal = sumVal + parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML);
            }

            document.getElementById("shopping").innerHTML = "Average Shopping = " + parseFloat(sumVal / rowCount);
            avgVal, sumVal = 0;

            //calculate average browsing usage
            for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
                sumVal = sumVal + parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML);
            }

            document.getElementById("browsing").innerHTML = "Average Shopping = " + parseFloat(sumVal / rowCount);
            avgVal, sumVal = 0;

            //calculate average browsing usage
            for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
                sumVal = sumVal + parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML);
            }

            document.getElementById("browsing").innerHTML = "Average Shopping = " + parseFloat(sumVal / rowCount);

            avgVal, sumVal = 0;
            //calculate average social usage
            for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
                sumVal = sumVal + parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[4].innerHTML);
            }

            document.getElementById("social").innerHTML = "Average Shopping = " + parseFloat(sumVal / rowCount);
        </script>

</body>



</html>
```

Here is the code for where the data comes from:

```
phoneRouter.route('/find')
    .post((req, res, next) => {
        phones.find({ name: req.body.name })
            .then((phonetaken) => {
                phones.find(req.body)
                    .then((phonefound) => {
                        res.render('oneFound.ejs', { 'phonelist': phonefound, title: 'All data recieved from user: ' + req.body.name }); //can use datadisplay
                    }, (err) => next(err));
            })
    })
```

I believe it is the `aggregate` method that would be used to calculate the averages here. How do I implement it?
How do I shorten that code, make it more presentable and more readable.
I think I could put a for loop inside of a for loop, but I'm not sure how to implement it and get all 4 averages displaying.

With this, I also want to generate a bar graph of the averages at the bottom of the page.

**How would I shorten my code/make it more efficient?
How would I generate a bar graph of the averages?**

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use whatever language you use for your loop to add up the totals in the loop and then just display them instead of using js to do it?

Comment: Thats a valid point, I'm using Node.js and mongoDB, so would I use the aggregation thing to do that?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to @ you @Pete 
I'm new to stack overflow

Comment: Please don't post code in the comment section, rather [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74641473/edit) your question to provide more information.

Comment: Just echoing what Pete said: the template you're using to render the page already has the data and you're already iterating over it. Do the math there and save yourself the hassle of having to extract it back out of the HTML you just rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to embed 2 `for` loops. Makes the script look much cleaner this way.

Check it out:

```
<script>
    var table = document.getElementById("table"),
        avgVal, sumVal = 0,
        rowCount = table.rows.length - 1;

    for (var x = 1; x < 5; x++) {
        for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
            sumVal = sumVal + parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[x].innerHTML);

        }
        if (x == 1) {
            var text = "Average Education = ";
        } else if (x == 2) {
            var text = "Average Shopping = ";
        } else if (x == 3) {
            var text = "Average Browsing = ";
        } else if (x == 4) {
            var text = "Average Social = "
        }
        document.getElementById(String(x)).innerHTML = text + parseFloat(sumVal / rowCount);
        avgVal, sumVal = 0;

    }
</script>
```

Then `span` tags **looked** like this:

```
<span id="education"></span><br>
<span id="shopping"></span><br>
<span id="browsing"></span><br>
<span id="social"></span>
```

**Now** they look like this:

```
<span id="1"></span><br>
<span id="2"></span><br>
<span id="3"></span><br>
<span id="4"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This becomes much easier if you give the `td`s a class for the column they are in.
Then you can just loop through an array of classnames which match the id of the output `span`. Collect the values into an array determine the average and render in the `span`.

```js
const cols = ["education", "shopping", "browsing", "social"]
const table = document.getElementById("table")
for (const col of cols) {
  const cells = table.querySelectorAll('.' + col)
  const values = []
  for (const cell of cells) {
    values.push(Number(cell.innerHTML))
  }
  const average = values.reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + a, 0) / values.length
  document.getElementById(col).innerHTML = `Average ${col}: ${average}`
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">

  <form action="/phone/find" method="post"></form>
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <table class="tableData" id="table">
      <caption>
        title
      </caption>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Education Usage</th>
          <th>Shopping Usage</th>
          <th>Searching/Browsing usage</th>
          <th>Social Media usage</th>
          <th>Date and Time</th>
          <th></th>

        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>

        <tr>

          <td>
            phonelist[i].name
          </td>
          <td class="education">
            1
          </td>
          <td class="shopping">
            1
          </td>
          <td class="browsing">
            1
          </td>
          <td class="social">
            1
          </td>
          <td>
            phonelist[i].createdAt
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="secret">
              <form action="/phone/delete" method="post"> <input type="String" value="phonelist[i].id" name="id" readonly><button type="Submit">Delete</button></form>
              <form action="/phone/update" method="post"> <input type="String" value="phonelist[i].id" name="id" readonly><button type="Submit">Update</button></form>
            </div>
          </td>


        </tr>
        <tr>

          <td>
            phonelist[i].name
          </td>
          <td class="education">
            1
          </td>
          <td class="shopping">
            2
          </td>
          <td class="browsing">
            3
          </td>
          <td class="social">
            4
          </td>
          <td>
            phonelist[i].createdAt
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="secret">
              <form action="/phone/delete" method="post"> <input type="String" value="phonelist[i].id" name="id" readonly><button type="Submit">Delete</button></form>
              <form action="/phone/update" method="post"> <input type="String" value="phonelist[i].id" name="id" readonly><button type="Submit">Update</button></form>
            </div>
          </td>


        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
  <span id="education"></span><br>
  <span id="shopping"></span><br>
  <span id="browsing"></span><br>
  <span id="social"></span>
  <script>
  </script>
```